# dataframe.to_sql into Teradata (this user does not have permission to create on LABUSERS) Datalab Table name

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata

I have an issue with the `dataframe.to_sql` when trying to use this function

The `dataframe.to_sql` does not recognize or separate the data lab name and the table name, instead it takes it all as a string to create a table. So it is trying to create it on the default root level and gives the error, this user does not have permission to create on *LABUSERS*.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f'teradata://{username}:{password}@tdprod:22/')

df.to_sql('data_lab.table_name', engine)
```

How can I use `df.to_sql` function and specify the datalab?

Comment: Try using *schema* parameter in [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html): `df.to_sql('table_name', engine, schema='data_lab')`

Comment: Thanks, schema. worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`schema` (str, optional)

Specify the schema (if database flavor supports this). If None, use default schema.

[to_sql documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)